# Compute lower bound on $\min_{E} \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2 I_n)(E)$ subject to $vol(E \cap H_n(r)) / vol(H_n(r)) \ge p$ where $H_n(r)$ is $n$-hemisphere

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-concentration, geometric-probability, isoperimetric-problems

Let $n \ge 2$ be an integer, which may be assumed to be **very large**. For $r > 0$, consider the hemi-sphere $H_n(r) := S_n(r) \cap (\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R^{n-1})$, where
$$
S_n(r):= \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \|x\|_2 \le r\}
$$
is the $n$-sphere of radius $r$.
and consider the measure $\lambda_n$ define on borel-measurable subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ by
$$
\lambda_n(E; r) := \frac{vol(E \cap H_n(r))}{vol(H_n(r))}.
$$

Finally, let $\sigma > 0$ and $\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2 I_n)$ be the standard $m$-dimensional gaussian distribution with variance $\sigma^2$.

> **Question 1.** For $p \in (0, 1)$, what is the borel-subset $\hat{E}$ of $\mathbb R^n$ which solves
>   $$
> \min_{E} \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2 I_n)(E)\text{ subject to } \lambda_n(E; r)\ge p. \tag{1}
> $$
>
> **Question 2.** Same question with the hemisphere $H_n(r)$ replaced with the sphere $S_n(r)$.
>
> **Question 4.** Same questions, but just provide the optimal objective value in (1), or a good lower-bound thereof.

## Notes

- Of course, any helpful pointers / refs for addressing such problems are more than welcome

---

## Edit

- **Question 3.** Cancelled as it would make sense in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\nu:=\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2 I_n)$ and $p\in[0,1]$.

Concerning Question 1: For the minimizing $E$, without loss of generality (wlog) we clearly have $E\subseteq H_n(r)$ and $\lambda_n(E;r)=p$. It is then clear that, subject to these conditions, wlog the set $E$ must consist of the points in $H_n(r)$ with the smallest density of $\nu$ wrt the Lebesgue measure; here, one might want to recall the [Neyman–Pearson (NP) lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma). So, wlog 
$$E=E_*:=H_n(r)\setminus H_n(s), \tag{1}
$$
where $s$ is the solution to the equation $\lambda_n(H_n(r)\setminus H_n(s);r)=p$, which can be rewritten as 
$$1-(s/r)^n=p.
$$
(See details on (1) below.)

The answer to Question 2 is quite similar. This also answers Question 4.

As for Question 3, it does not quite make sense as stated, because the limits $\lambda_n(E;0)$ and $\lambda_n(E;\infty)$ will in general not exist, and also in view of the answers to Questions 1 and 2. Perhaps, Question 3 was intended as a relaxed, limit version of Questions 1 and 2.

**Details on (1):** Basically, here I will give a proof of the NP lemma, which I think is better than the one given in the linked Wikipedia article. Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$, and let $g:=\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}$. Let real $c>0$ be such that for all $x\in H_n(r)$ we have $g(x)<c\iff x\in E_*$. Then for any Borel $E\subseteq H_n(r)$ 
$$(1_E-1_{E_*})(g-c)\ge0. \tag{2}
$$
Assuming now that $\lambda(E)=\lambda(E_*)$, expanding the left-hand side of (2), and then integrating there wrt $\lambda$, we get $\nu(E)\ge\nu(E_*)$, as claimed.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. Indeed Question 3 was asked in a hurry. Deleted. Do you mind adding a one-line sentence explaining how you've applied NP here ?

Comment: Intuitively, by symmetry arguments, the set which solves the set can be taken a horse-shoe $H_n(r)\setminus H_n(s)$ as you're proposed (then one would chose $s$ to meet the volume constraint). What I'm missing is the NP link.

Comment: @dohmatob : I have added the details on the NP lemma.

Comment: OK great, thanks for the details.

Comment: On second thought, one thing which seems mysterious in this solution is that the gaussian distribution $\nu$ has barely been used in the arguments. **Q:** what property of $\nu$ has been used by the construction of the solution, apart (perhaps) the fact that $\nu$ has density w.r.t Lebesgue ?

Comment: @dohmatob : The following two properties of the density $g$ were used in the answer: (i) that $g(x)$ depends only on $\|x\|_2$ and (ii) that $g(x)$ is a decreasing continuous function of $\|x\|_2$. These two properties were used in the sentence "Let real $c>0$ be such that for all $x\in H_n(r)$ we have $g(x)<c\iff x\in E_*$."

Comment: OK, makes sense. Thanks. Then your construction should hold for densities of the form $\varphi(-\|x\|_p)d\mathcal L(x)$, where $\varphi$ is increasing nonnegative and $p \in [1,\infty]$, and the $\ell_2$ hemisphere replaced with the $\ell_p$ hemisphere.